# Scattering amplitude ($s$-, $t$-, $u$-channels)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, scattering

> Given the Lagrangian
>   $$\mathscr{L}=\bar{\psi}\left(i\partial\!\!\!/-m\right)\psi+\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial\phi\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}M^2\phi^2-g\bar\psi\psi\phi^2-g'\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\psi\partial^\mu\phi,$$
>   calculate the scattering amplitude
>   $$i\mathcal{M}\left(\psi(p_1)+\psi(p_2)\rightarrow\psi(p'_1)+\psi(p'_2)\right)$$
>   at the first non-vanishing perturbative order in $g$ and $g'$.

For both kind of interacions, we need second order processes. Since $\psi$ particles are identical, for both kind of vertices there are both $t$- and $u$-channels; but I can't decide if there's also a $s$-channel. Are $s$- and $t$-channels the same? Or should I treat them as separate processes (as they should be), but with $s\leftrightarrow t$?